# text-align not working in FF and chrome

Tags: asp.net, html, css, database-design, alignment

I have an asp page where I am trying to align in center. The following is the specific line,

```
<td style="height: 50px; background-color: #ffffe0; text-align: center; ">
```

This code is working fine in IE, but in FF and chrome, the text is aligned in left. If I change the same code as

```
<td style="height: 50px; background-color: #ffffe0; text-align: -moz-center; ">
```

Then the alignment is working only in FF. IE and chrome fails :(. Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue ?

**UPDATED:**

The whole table structure looks like this,

```
<table style="width: 900px; height: 500px; background-color: gray;">

   <tbody>
       <tr>

      <td style="height: 70px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #fffff0; text-align: center !important; width: 160px;">

        <div id="abc" style="height:40px;width:80px;text-align: center !important ;left: 0px; position: relative; top: 0px" onscroll="JavaScript:document.getElementById(somejavascrpt)'">

                <input id="button" type="image" style="height:40px;width:60px;border-width:0px;z-index: 104; left: 4px; text-align: center !important position: absolute; top: 2px" src="../images/help.png" name="help">
        </div>
      </td>
```

Comment: `text-align:center;` on a td should work in all browsers, if it does not, you probably have another class that overwrite it. try `text-align: center !important;` to force the center

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use both `text-align: center;` and `text-align: -moz-center;`

```
<td style="height: 50px; background-color: #ffffe0; 
    text-align: -moz-center;text-align: center; ">
```

### Edit 1

You can also try

```
  <td style="height: 50px; background-color: #ffffe0;text-align: center!important;">
```

### Edit 2

You can use fire bug and see what rule is applied on your `td`
Some link how to use firebug
http://www.studiopress.com/tips/using-firebug.htm
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/10-reasons-why-you-should-be-using-firebug/

Comment: Not really, it has to work with simple `text-align`. Never had any issue with that. If it doesn't work for him, he has probably some other rule that's overriding this...

Comment: @walther you are right. He can also use `!important` with `text-align:center!important`

Comment: Thank you. I will check now

Comment: can you check with firebug what classes or attribute are applied on your td.

Comment: <td style="height: 70px; vertical-align: middle; background-color: #ffe4e1; text-align: center !important; width: 160px;>

Comment: This is the td attribute. I tried using text-align: center !important; text-align: -moz-center together. It works fine in firefox. It is left aligned in IE

Comment: have you checked weather any other rule is being applied at run time?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work for you, you have some other rule somewhere else that is overriding your style. `Text-align` is perfectly all-browser-friendly.

I'd suggest two things:

- stop using inline styles. Styling doesn't have a place in your html, it should be defined in a separate file.
- use webdeveloper tools in your browser to find out which rules apply to your TD and make sure you've defined only one rule

Comment: @Cyril, I see it, but unless you have some extra old archaic version of FF, text-align works on TD without any problem. I've just verified it multiple times in my browser (actually in multiple browsers). If you have a live website that you can provide a link for, do it. I can't debug your whole application using few lines of code. And as I've said, don't use inline styles, it's very ugly to say at least.

Comment: No, the website is not live yet. Anyway thanks for the help. I will get it done :)

Answer (score 0):

There may be different ways to do this. One of the ways is to use left margin. Unless your position is relative, you may use this. For example-

```
style="margin:0 0 0 100px"
```

Comment: Might be! That's why I said there are different ways to do.

Comment: Yes, but some are really bad. Defining a fixed margin is a bad idea.. What if he decides to alter the size of his table at some later point in the future? He'd have to modify all of his rules.. Not mentioning kinda problematic attitude of some browsers towards calculating padding/margin.

Answer (score 0):

Try using html attribute.

```
<td align="center" style="height: 50px; background-color: #ffffe0;">
```

Comment: please don't use the `align` attribute on `td` elements. It is deprecated. In general, don't use HTML attributes to affect style or presentation. Use CSS instead.